# Beginner in Clojure: trying to apply function to items in list

Tags: clojure

So I've got this list returned from calling lines:

```
(def lines  (into () (clojure.string/split-lines (slurp "input.txt"))))
```

And I've got these two functions:

```
(defn tokenize-line [x] (clojure.string/split x #" " ))

(defn tokenize-list  [lst] (for [x lst] (tokenize-line [x])))
```

When I pass `(lines)` as a parameter to `tokenize-list`, I get this error:

```
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

I can't figure out where this error comes from, any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In clojure `(lines)` means "call the function lines with no arguments". As we see from your definition, `lines` is not a function, it's a list.

Also, in `(tokenize-line [x])` you pass a vector, containing the String x, to a function that expects a String.

Further, when you run `(into () ...)` this takes something that was already a sequence, and turns it into a reversed sequence (because of the behavior of `()` when you add elements, they end up in reversed order).

Comment: Thank you a ton, again I'm brand new to this, so this really helps!